# Split variable line by line python

Tags: python, http

I am trying to split a `HTTP` request into different chunks using python (each chunk is separated by a line)

here is my code:

```
request='''GET / HTTP/1.1


Host: '+str(host)+':'+str(port)+'''

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: keep-alive'''.splitlines(True)
```

When this is run I get this:

```
...
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

How is that, in any way, a list object?
What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Cast the list using `str()`?

Comment: the list is created by `splitlines()`. Add parens around the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `splitlines()` method is being applied before the concatenation operators so you are trying to append a list to the strings in the start of the statement. Wrap everything in ()'s to form the whole string before calling `splitlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

`str(host)` is a string. `.splitlines()` returns a `list`- split on newline characters (a multi-line string implicitly contains these).

You get the error because the `splitlines()` is done first, leaving you with separate strings and a `list`. They are different types and obviously you cannot add them together.

You need to override the precedence by enclosing the entire concatenated string in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the last `.splitlines()` is evaluated first, and then you are left with a list of strings to which you try to append a string, which is not possible. You have to override the precedence with parentheses.